# How to use MariaDB Connector/J with Pyspark for JDBC?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I'm using Pyspark Spark 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 and want to export data to a MariaDB server using JDBC.

I'm specifying the Connector/J jar on the pyspark command line like this:

`$ pyspark --jars /usr/share/java/mariadb-java-client.jar`

However, when I to use the JDBC connection I get the following error:

```
>>> df1 = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]).toDF(("a", "b", "c"))
>>> df1.write.format("jdbc") \
... .mode("overwrite") \
... .option("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/testDatabase?user=foo&password=bar") \
... .option("dbtable", "example") \
... .save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 825, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o60.save.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$2(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

>>>
```

Because of `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` I assume I need some additional configuration for Connector/J to be invoked. I'm not seeing how to to it though. What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifiy the mariadb driver class `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` using `driver` option when writing:

```
df1.write.format("jdbc") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDatabase?user=foo&password=bar") \
    .option("dbtable", "example") \
    .save()
```

See [Usage](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-columnstore-with-spark/#usage) in the docs.

Comment: Example now throws the following error:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=34) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"a" BIGINT , "b" BIGINT , "c" BIGINT )' at line 1`

Not sure what's wrong with that yet, but it's obviously past the driver setup problem and getting the error back from MariaDB.

Thanks!

Comment: Fix: I needed url to be `jdbc:mysql:...` not `jdbc:mariadb:...`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still facing this error,

use mysql in url, not mariadb.

the jdbc url should be like `jdbc:mysql:{host} ...` in place of `jdbc:mariadb:{host} ...`.