# PySpark - Juypter Notebook - Line magic function `%scala` not found

Tags: scala, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm studying PySpark using Juypter Notebooks and I faced the following error while trying using scala driver to interact with the database JDBC connection.

[image]

```
%scala Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
```

Comment: is it not ```%%scala```?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343272/how-to-use-mariadb-connector-j-with-pyspark-for-jdbc
answer your question?

Comment: executing dataframe_mysql line without defining scala line giving error Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Comment: from what I read, I have to define driver class using %scala, but this is not recognized on my juypter notebook environment, maybe something is missing., NOTE: I'm running Jupyter notebook on my local machine, not using data bricks cluster.

Comment: Apache Spark provides a JDBC data source and is capable of connecting to virtually any RDBMS that supports JDBC connections and has a JDBC driver available. However, it doesn't come bundled with any drivers; they need to be procured from the respective RDBMS provider, and the driver needs to be configured to your Spark cluster to be available to your Spark application.